# Google Maps InfoBox not triggering event on iOS as expected

Tags: jquery, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mobile-safari

I'm using Infobox. I'm able to load all the markers, load different content inside each infobox and "properly" trigger then. Then where start the issues:

1) On Desktop/iOS my Toggle event just works after the second click. Basically it moves a div up and down. See code Below:

```
//Setting up the marker
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 draggable: false,
                 position: latlng6,
                 visible: true
                });

                var boxText = document.createElement("div");
                boxText.class = "test";
                boxText.style.cssText = "height: 0px;";
                boxText.innerHTML =  "<div id='top'><p>SUSSAN</p><a href='#' class='info'>+ info</a>" 
                                    + "<h2></h2>"
                                    + "</div>" 
                                    + "<div id='promo'>"
                                    + "<div class='badge'>"
                                    + "<img src='hot@2x.png'>"
                                    + "</div>"
                                    + "<p>TODAY UP TO 70% OFF</p>"
                                    + "</div>";



                var myOption = {
                         content: boxText
                        ,disableAutoPan: false
                        ,maxWidth: 0
                        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-128, -161)
                        ,zIndex: null
                        ,boxStyle: { 
                          background: "url('') no-repeat"
                          ,opacity: 1
                          ,width: "280px"
                          ,height: "0px"

                         }
                        ,closeBoxMargin: "36px 25px 0px 0px"
                        ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                        ,isHidden: false
                  ,zIndex: 999999
                        ,pane: "floatPane"
                        ,enableEventPropagation: false
                };

                var ib = new InfoBox(myOption);
                boxList.push(ib);



//ANIMATE MORE INFO  
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(boxList[i].content_,'click', function() {

             $("#promo").toggle( function(a) {
             $("#top").animate({top: 14}, 200)},
             function() {
             $("#top").animate({top: 50}, 200);;

          });
```

2) On the iOS, even with the first issue, when I "tap" over the div "promo" first time the Infobox just disappear, on the Desktop, it doesn't happen. If I back, open the infobox again and tap over div "promo" it work as the desktop. I believe this second issue is connected with the first. But not sure why it just happen on iOS. =/ Appreciate any help.

See the live example http://www.clickin.com.au/fashion/hottie4.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you anything about the iOS-issue, but regarding to first issue:

The toggle-handler is attached **after** the first click, that's why the first click cannot trigger the toggle-event.

You may attach the toggle directly instead of waiting for the first click(replace your current click-handler for boxList[i].content_ with the following code)

```
$("#promo",boxList[i].content_)
                .toggle( 
                  function(a) {
                    $("#top").animate({top: 14}, 200);
                  },
                  function() {
                    $("#top").animate({top: 50}, 200);
              });
```

Comment: Solved the first issue, worked just like a charm! Thanks @Dr.Molle . Regarding to the second issue, I added "dragstart" instead "click" on    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() { . It solved the problem on my first click where the infbox was disappearing on ios since now, the box just disappear after I tap to move the map, however, it's not the best solution for what I would like to achieve =/.